# MS Visual Studio 2019: how to change background color of text editor's tooltip window

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2019

Winforms project, a form has some code in the Form_KeyDown event.

When i hover the mouse over the name of the event (Form_KeyDown) in the text editor of the form, a tooltip window appears. Going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors i've searched around but i could not find how to change the tooltip's background color, either in Show Settings for: "Text Editor" or "Editor Tooltip" or "[All Text Tool Windows]". Where is the setting for changing the tooltip's background color (if any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, i have finally found the answer here: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Hardcoded-tooltip-background-colors-enfo/43237?space=8&ftype=problem&preview2=true&q=tooltip%20window%20background%20color)

Check answer by Paul Chen in that link.

> This was fixed in some update of VS2015.
> Switch "Show settings for:" to "Environment" and you'll see "Tooltip" and "Tooltip Border", try change the "Background Color" of them.